# Stolen Social Security number used to obtain MasterCard - does my friend owe any money?

Tags: united-states, identity-theft, mastercard, liability

So... my friend just told me that someone used his SSN to create a MasterCard and used around $6000. So he needs quick money from me. I personally do not understand how. Even if someone can make a MasterCard with my friend's personal info, does MasterCard allow you to use $6000 without deposit??

How did it happen? Can I believe my friend??

Comment: If my cards were stolen, I'd have to use cash if I had no other card. Was he living off credit cards? Why the urgent need? Something sounds wrong here, I'd be very careful.

Comment: Even then it's normally a matter of a few days time at the most to have a replacement issued for a card that was stolen or has been used fraudulently.   I agree that something seems wrong here (more details in my answer)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it's just an ordinary credit card I'd think he could merely dispute the charges, since he's saying they 'created' (which I presume means applied for and received) a card, it should not affect his accounts directly.  And especially since application details may be bogus, he should be able to prove it was not him.

Even if they got HIS credit card number, he should be able to dispute those charges that are not his, especially if they went to a different address, or were charged someplace (like another city) where he was not present at that time.

OTOH, if they created a DEBIT card that was linked to his bank account somehow, well then, that could be a lot more difficult to recover from, but even then, if it's not his signature that was used to apply for the card, or on any charges that had to be signed for etc, he should be able to dispute it and get the bank to put the money back in his account since it will be a case of forgery etc.

The big problem with ID theft is people tend to ruin your credit rating, and you end up having to fend off bill collectors etc. The primary thing it costs you (speaking from experience of having checks stolen and forged using a fake drivers license) is the TIME and hassle of getting everything straightened out and put right.  In my case it took a few hours at the credit union, and all the money was back, in a new account (the old one having been closed) when I left.  Dealing with all the poor merchants that were taken, and with bill collectors on the other hand took months.  but I never once in the process needed 'quick money' from anyone.

So the need for 'quick money' seems a bit doubtful.  I'd want a lot more details of exactly why he needs money from you.

Refer your friend to this [Federal Trade Commission site](http://www.ftc.gov/bcp/edu/microsites/idtheft/consumers/defend.html) and make sure he takes the steps listed, and especially pays attention to the parts about keeping notes of every single person he talks with, including name, date, time, and pertinent details of the conversation.  If he has some idea HOW this happened (as in a robbery) then report it to the proper authorities, and insist on getting a case number.

talking with bill collectors is the worst, just trying to get ahold of them when they send you letters (and talk to a person, not a recorded number with instructions on how to pay them) is sometimes nearly impossible (google was my friend)  and a lot of times they didn't want to back off till I gave them the case number with the police, that somehow magically made it 'real' to them and not just my telling them a story.

Answer (score 1):

If the card has a credit limit of more than $6,000, then sure, someone can rack up that much in charges.  Charges on a regular credit card are an unsecured loan, so having the money on deposit isn't necessary.

But if what you said is true, your friend has had his identity stolen.  [Here are some steps he should take.](http://www.bbbonline.org/idtheft/stolenid.asp)  Whether you loan him money (or believe him) are separate questions.

Comment: Loaning him money is the same question, if the identity was stolen, **no loan**.  If it wasn't stolen and he is fibbing, *no loan*.